# Tabbed Fragment Only Displays First Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have a tabbed fragment outlined by the class below.

There are two tabs with lists of information, Friends and Groups. The issue I am having, is that the Group list renders first within the Friends tab, then disappears allowing the Friends list to render within the Friends tab. However, the upon swiping to the Groups tab, the groups list never renders.

How can this be resolved?

Tabbed Activity:

```
public class InvitingFriendsGroupsToEvents extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inviting_friends_groups_to_events);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_inviting_friends_groups_to_events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inviting_friends_groups_to_events, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            //  Need to build
            //  Order/first appearing will be specific to time of day, ie. if in morning, then breakfast/brunch, if midday then lunch, late then dinner
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new InviteFriendsToEventsFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new InviteGroupsToEventsFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Friends";
                case 1:
                    return "Groups";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Friend Tab:

```
public class InviteFriendsToEventsFragment extends Fragment {
    // ie. once a fiend is invited, it will show their group on the second tab, the name, who invite them

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    SaveSharedPreference preference = new SaveSharedPreference();

    final Firebase myFeastFirebase = new Firebase(Constants.getFirebaseUrl());
    Firebase presentEventMembers;
    Firebase myFriends;
    Firebase sentFriendEventInvites; // this will be the grayed out standing invitation

    Firebase eventMemberInviteNeedSync;

    ValueEventListener getFriendsListener;
    ValueEventListener getEventMembersListener;
    ValueEventListener getAlreadyInvitedFriendsListener;

    String eventID;
    String eventName;

    ArrayList<Member> mEventMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Member> mFriends = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Member> mAlreadyInvited = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<FriendInvite> mFriendsFinalInviteStatuses = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_friends_to_events, container, false);

        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        eventID = extras.getString("eventID");
        eventName = extras.getString("eventName");
        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Event ID: " + eventID);
        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Event Name" + eventName);

        //Generate list View from ArrayList
        // Get present group members
        presentEventMembers = myFeastFirebase.child("eventMembers").child(eventID);
        myFriends = myFeastFirebase.child("friends").child(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext()));
        sentFriendEventInvites = myFeastFirebase.child("userEventMemberInviteSent").child(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext())).child(eventID);

        eventMemberInviteNeedSync = myFeastFirebase.child("eventMemberInviteNeedSync");

        getAlreadyInvitedFriendsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot inviteSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Member invitedFriend = new Member();
                    invitedFriend.setUserUID(inviteSnapshot.getKey());
                    invitedFriend.setUserName(inviteSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                    mAlreadyInvited.add(invitedFriend);

                    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Invite Sent userName is: " + inviteSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Invite Sent ID is: " + inviteSnapshot.getKey().toString());

                }

                // Here will be the operation to get the proper setting for
                // First: remove from friends, those already in the group:
                mFriends.removeAll(mEventMembers);

                // Then add to the invite group
                for (Member friend : mFriends) {
                    FriendInvite groupMemberInvite = new FriendInvite();
                    groupMemberInvite.setUserName(friend.getUserName());
                    groupMemberInvite.setUserUID(friend.getUserUID());

                    if (mAlreadyInvited.contains(friend)) {
                        groupMemberInvite.setInvitedAlready(true);
                    }
                    mFriendsFinalInviteStatuses.add(groupMemberInvite);

                    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Final List UserName is: " + groupMemberInvite.getUserName());
                    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Final List UserID is: " + groupMemberInvite.getUserUID());
                    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Final List InviteStatus is: " + groupMemberInvite.isInvitedAlready());
                }
                //dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
                dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.country_info, mFriendsFinalInviteStatuses);
                ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                // Assign adapter to ListView
                listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        };

        getFriendsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot friendSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (!friendSnapshot.getKey().equals(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext()))) {
                        Member friend = new Member();
                        friend.setUserUID(friendSnapshot.getKey());
                        friend.setUserName(friendSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString());

                        mFriends.add(friend);

                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Friend userName is: " + friendSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString());
                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Friend user ID is: " + friendSnapshot.getKey().toString());
                    }
                }

                // after getting friends
                sentFriendEventInvites.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getAlreadyInvitedFriendsListener);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Firebase Error: " + firebaseError.toString());

            }
        };

        getEventMembersListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot groupMemberSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (!groupMemberSnapshot.getKey().equals(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext()))) {
                        Member groupMember = new Member();
                        groupMember.setUserUID(groupMemberSnapshot.getKey());
                        groupMember.setUserName(groupMemberSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                        mEventMembers.add(groupMember);

                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Group member userName is: " + groupMemberSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Group member user ID is: " + groupMemberSnapshot.getKey().toString());
                    }
                }

//                 upon completion of getting groups
                myFriends.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getFriendsListener);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Firebase Error: " + firebaseError.toString());

            }
        };
        presentEventMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getEventMembersListener);

        //confirmFriendInvites();

        return view;
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendInvite> {

        private ArrayList<FriendInvite> groupMemberInviteList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<FriendInvite> groupMemberInviteList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, groupMemberInviteList);
            this.groupMemberInviteList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.groupMemberInviteList.addAll(groupMemberInviteList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView inviteSent;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); // here it is
                holder.inviteSent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite_already_sent);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        FriendInvite groupMemberInivited = (FriendInvite) cb.getTag();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                        " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        groupMemberInivited.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            FriendInvite groupMemberInvite = groupMemberInviteList.get(position);

            holder.checkBox.setText(groupMemberInvite.getUserName());
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(groupMemberInvite.isSelected());
            holder.checkBox.setTag(groupMemberInvite);

            // Check if already invited, if so, should remove
            if (groupMemberInvite.isInvitedAlready() == true) {

                holder.checkBox.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                holder.checkBox.setClickable(false);

                holder.inviteSent.setText("Invite Already Sent");
            } else {
                holder.inviteSent.setText("");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

Group Tab:

public class InviteGroupsToEventsFragment extends Fragment {
    // ie. once a fiend is invited, it will show their group on the second tab, the name, who invite them

```
GroupInviteCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
SaveSharedPreference preference = new SaveSharedPreference();

final Firebase myFeastFirebase = new Firebase(Constants.getFirebaseUrl());
Firebase presentEventMembers;
Firebase sentFriendEventInvites; // this will be the grayed out standing invitation

Firebase mGroups;
Firebase mGroupMembers;

Firebase eventMemberInviteNeedSync;

ValueEventListener getFriendsListener;
ValueEventListener getEventMembersListener;
ValueEventListener getAlreadyInvitedFriendsListener;
ValueEventListener getUsersGroups;

String eventID;
String eventName;

ArrayList<Member> mEventMembers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Member> mFriends = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Member> mAlreadyInvited = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<FriendInvite> mFriendsFinalInviteStatuses = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<GroupInvite> mUsersGroups = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_groups_to_events, container, false);

    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    eventID = extras.getString("eventID");
    eventName = extras.getString("eventName");
    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Event ID: " + eventID);
    Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Event Name" + eventName);

    //Generate list View from ArrayList
    // Get present group members
    presentEventMembers = myFeastFirebase.child("eventMembers").child(eventID);
    mGroupMembers = myFeastFirebase.child("groupMembers"); // will append: .child("")
    mGroups = myFeastFirebase.child("usersGroups").child(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext()));
    sentFriendEventInvites = myFeastFirebase.child("userEventMemberInviteSent").child(preference.getUserSyncID(getContext())).child(eventID);

    eventMemberInviteNeedSync = myFeastFirebase.child("eventMemberInviteNeedSync");

    getUsersGroups = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot inviteSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                GroupInvite invitedGroup = new GroupInvite();
                invitedGroup.setGroupSyncID(inviteSnapshot.getKey());
                invitedGroup.setGroupName(inviteSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                mUsersGroups.add(invitedGroup);

                Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Invite Sent userName is: " + inviteSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                Log.v("InvitingFriendsToEvents", "Invite Sent ID is: " + inviteSnapshot.getKey().toString());

            }

            dataAdapter = new GroupInviteCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.event_invites_groups, mUsersGroups);
            ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    };


    mGroups.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getUsersGroups);


    return view;
}

private class GroupInviteCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GroupInvite> {

    private ArrayList<GroupInvite> groupInviteList;

    public GroupInviteCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                    ArrayList<GroupInvite> groupInviteList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, groupInviteList);
        this.groupInviteList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.groupInviteList.addAll(groupInviteList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView inviteSent;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.event_invites_groups, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); // here it is
            holder.inviteSent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invite_already_sent);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    GroupInvite groupInvited = (GroupInvite) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    groupInvited.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        GroupInvite groupInvite = groupInviteList.get(position);

        holder.checkBox.setText(groupInvite.getName());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(groupInvite.isSelected());
        holder.checkBox.setTag(groupInvite);

        // Check if already invited, if so, should remove
        if (groupInvite.isInvitedAlready() == true) {

            holder.checkBox.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.checkBox.setClickable(false);

            holder.inviteSent.setText("Invite Already Sent");
        } else {
            holder.inviteSent.setText("");
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the below block of code outside  getUsersGroups = new ValueEventListener()

```
         dataAdapter = new GroupInviteCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.event_invites_groups, mUsersGroups);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ValueEventListener() only executes the override methods. My guess is that the above code never runs.Try and let me know if it works. If it doesnt will debug further.

Comment: It is an asynchronous operation, therefore it must be inside of the callback. I tested your approach and still blank, only now, it does not even render in the Friends fragment and disappear, it does not render at all

Comment: Can we enter a chat?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that. Anyways why not use the FirebaseUI for your ListView. It takes care of synchronization. Is it feasible to use in your project?

Comment: The problem is not firebase, it is the tabs. Why does my Group tab render on top of my Friends tab, then disappear, allowing the friends tab to render?

Comment: I opted to simply refactor using recyclerview, everything is working now